# AMDP selects false records contrary to OpenSQL

Tags: abap, hana, amdp

I am learning AMDP and I found out that the result obtained from this is very different from normal select query in ABAP AS. 
I am using below code in AMDP:

```
ex_gt_data = select a.vbeln,
                   a.kunnr,
                   a.bukrs_vf,
                   b.erdat,
                   b.lsmeng,
                   b.posnr,
                   b.matnr
                   from vbak as a
                   join vbap as b
                   on a.vbeln = b.vbeln;
```

followed by APPLY_FILTER function.
This query return multiple values in BUKRS_VF field. If I use normal select query like below:

```
SELECT a~vbeln,
     a~bukrs_vf,
     a~kunnr,
     b~erdat,
     b~lsmeng,
     b~posnr,
     b~matnr
     FROM vbak AS a
     JOIN vbap AS b
     ON a~vbeln = b~vbeln
     INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_vbak)
     WHERE a~vbeln IN @s_vbeln.
```

it generates required result.

Can anybody tell me why this difference between AMDP and normal select query?

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that adding

> MANDT
>   field 
>   solves the issue. i have added an pass by value parameter in method and used in query as
>
> where a.mandt = im_mandt.

Dont know whether this is the correct solution.Please advise.

Comment: OpenSQL always quietly adds the `WHERE MANDT = xxx` condition, unless you explicitly suppress it with the [`CLIENT SPECIFIED` addition](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_client.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_2@2@). AMDPs don't handle clients automatically, you have to add these conditions on your own. So yes, your solution is exactly the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Many discrete useful pieces were given, but I am here to give a comprehensive answer to the question.

First of all, ABAP CDS views do **not** respect client data automatically like it is done in OpenSQL. BTW, the same is true for HANA CDS but judging on indirect indicators of your question it was about ABAP CDS based on HANA backend, rather that HANA CDS. Ya?

What is the proper way of client handling in ABAP CDS views?

1. `@ClientHandling.type #CLIENT_DEPENDENT` annotation must be added to view.
   Default type is `#INHERITED` but for more straightforwardness it's better make it explicitly dependent.
2. `@ClientHandling.algorithm` is an optional field and can be omitted. There is [a complex set of rules](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abencds_client_handling.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENCDS_CLIENT_HANDLING_2) which determines how the client is calculated but in your case you can just don't specify it, implicit `#AUTOMATED` way will be used and client column will be implicitly added to `ON` conditions of your JOIN.
3. Client column must exist in view and should be either

   - selected via SELECT statement with either name or alias
   - have MANDT name manually set
   - if the latter is absent CLIENT column is used
   - if neither CLIENT nor MANDT column is not found the syntax error is thrown
4. No other actions needed, client is addressed implicitly like in OpenSQL case.

But! Here we are speaking about AMDP procedure, not simple CDS, so the things are more tricky.

The first and foremost, for all this to work a special **CDS SESSION CLIENT CURRENT** AMDP declaration is mandatory in a method signature:

```
 AMDP OPTIONS READ-ONLY     
              CDS SESSION CLIENT CURRENT
```

the declaration makes implicit passing of `$session.client` var into the implementation of AMDP procedure. In the default `CURRENT` syntax variant it is equal to `sy-mandt` value of ABAP AS.

After that you can use `$session.client` explicitly with tables inside AMDP

```
SELECT * FROM vbak WHERE vbak.mandt = $session.client;
```

or implicitly with client-dependent views

```
lt_vbak = APPLY_FILTER ("Z_CDS_VIEW", :iv_where);
```

Comment: This is a nice & comprehensive summary. The original question didn’t have anything about CDS at all, though...

Comment: I tried to cover all potentially related client issues :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't HAVE to add the MANDT parameter to get the client number in AMDP/generated SQL script. Rather, you can use SESSION_CONTEXT('CLIENT')

So, your above query would look like the following:

```
ex_gt_data = select a.vbeln,
                   a.kunnr,
                   a.bukrs_vf,
                   b.erdat,
                   b.lsmeng,
                   b.posnr,
                   b.matnr
                   from vbak as a
                   join vbap as b
                   on a.vbeln = b.vbeln
                   and a.mandt = SESSION_CONTEXT('CLIENT');
```

There are many more things you can achieve using SESSION_CONTEXT. Used properly, it's a powerful tool at your disposal.

Best Regards,
Gopal Nair.